# Сапёр, открытие пустых клеток вокруг

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, c++

Подскажите, как мне организовать алгоритм открытия пустых клеток вокруг нажатой. Есть две матрицы поля (open, mine), открытых клеток и мин соответственно. Пробовал так

```
void OpenK(int x, int y)
{
    if(mine[x-1][y-1]==0 && open[x-1][y-1]==0)
    {
        open[x-1][y-1]=1;
        OpenK(x-1,y-1);
    }
    if(mine[x-1][y]==0 && open[x-1][y]==0)
    {
        open[x-1][y]=1;
        OpenK(x-1,y);
    }
    if(mine[x-1][y+1]==0 && open[x-1][y+1]==0)
    {
        open[x-1][y+1]=1;
        OpenK(x-1,y+1);
    }
    if(mine[x][y+1]==0 && open[x][y+1]==0)
    {
        open[x][y+1]=1;
        OpenK(x,y+1);
    }
    if(mine[x+1][y+1]==0 && open[x+1][y+1]==0)
    {
        open[x+1][y+1]=1;
        OpenK(x+1,y+1);
    }
    if(mine[x+1][y]==0 && open[x+1][y]==0)
    {
        open[x+1][y]=1;
        OpenK(x+1,y);
    }
    if(mine[x+1][y-1]==0 && open[x+1][y-1]==0)
    {
        open[x+1][y-1]=1;
        OpenK(x+1,y-1);
    }
    if(mine[x][y-1]==0 && open[x][y-1]==0)
    {
        open[x][y-1]=1;
        OpenK(x,y-1);
    }
}
```

При вызове передаются координаты нажатой клетки, но естественно это не работает, а других идей как это реализовать нет

Comment: Алгоритм flood fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте очередь клеток и добавьте в нее нажатую клетку. Далее в цикле извлекайте из очереди по одной клетке и отмечайте ее как "нажатую". Если в смежных клетках нет мин, добавляйте в очередь все смежные клетки.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так с рекурсией:

```
inline void open_zeros(uint8_t X, uint8_t Y)
{

    field[X][Y] = char(Hfield[X][Y]) + 48;
    if (X == 0 && Y == 0)
    {
        if (field[X][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X, Y + 1);
            }
        }


        if (field[X + 1][Y] != '#')
        {
            field[X + 1][Y] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y);
            }
        }

        if (field[X + 1][Y + 1] != '#')
        {

            field[X + 1][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (X == 0 && Y == 9)
    {
        if (field[X][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X, Y - 1);
            }
        }

        if (field[X + 1][Y] != '#')
        {

            field[X + 1][Y] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y);
            }
        }

        if (field[X + 1][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X + 1][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (X == 0 && Y != 0 && Y != 9)
    {
        if (field[X][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X, Y - 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X, Y + 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X + 1][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X + 1][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y - 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X + 1][Y] != '#')
        {
            field[X + 1][Y] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y);
            }
        }
        if (field[X + 1][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X + 1][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (X == 9 && Y == 0)
    {
        if (field[X][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X, Y + 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (X == 9 && Y == 9)
    {
        if (field[X][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X, Y - 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y - 1] != '#')
        {

            field[X - 1][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (X == 9 && Y != 0 && Y != 9)
    {
        if (field[X][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X, Y - 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X, Y + 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y - 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (X != 0 && X != 9 && Y == 0)
    {
        if (field[X][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X, Y + 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y + 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X + 1][Y] != '#')
        {
            field[X + 1][Y] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y);
            }
        }
        if (field[X + 1][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X + 1][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (X != 0 && X != 9 && Y == 9)
    {
        if (field[X][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X, Y - 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y - 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X + 1][Y] != '#')
        {
            field[X + 1][Y] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y);
            }
        }
        if (field[X + 1][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X + 1][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (field[X][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X, Y - 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X, Y + 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y - 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X - 1][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X - 1][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X - 1][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X - 1][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X - 1][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X - 1][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X - 1, Y + 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X + 1][Y] != '#')
        {
            field[X + 1][Y] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y);
            }
        }
        if (field[X + 1][Y - 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X + 1][Y - 1] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y - 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y - 1] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y - 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y - 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y - 1);
            }
        }
        if (field[X + 1][Y + 1] != '#')
        {
            field[X + 1][Y + 1] = char(Hfield[X + 1][Y + 1]) + 48;
            if (Hfield[X + 1][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y + 1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```